# Email Signature Text Wrapping and Resizing in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, email, html-email

I'm having some issues with my email signature wrapping in Apple Mail on iOS seen here:

[image]

I would like the signature to appear (non-wrapping and sized to fit within screen width) as it does on a desktop email client, such as Apple mail on OS X:

[image]

This is the code that I am currently using. If anyone can provide guidance on where I'm going wrong, I would appreciate it.

```html
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">
                  <a href="http://bit.ly/1roJoAu">
                    <img alt="Motion Source" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/YG8iERP.jpg" title="My Website">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td width="100%">
                  <span style="text-align: left; color: #797C79; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold">
                                        First Last</span><span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #797C79; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: normal">&nbsp;|&nbsp; Media Producer</span>
                  <br>
                  <span style="text-align: left; color: #797C79; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">

                                        mobile&nbsp;(555)
                                        555-5555&nbsp;|&nbsp;fax&nbsp;(555) 555-5555<br></span>

                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span style="line-height: 3px; font-size: 3px;">
                                                            &nbsp;<br>
                                                        </span>
                          <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; color: #D0913D; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;">
                                                            <a href="http://website.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">website</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://linkd.in/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">LinkedIn</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="mailto:none@me.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">email</a>
                                                        </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you using for testing? Are you only testing in Apple Mail?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use media queries to shrink your text size that dramatically. To be honest, the long text lines you have there are probably too small to display on a phone. You should be breaking your lines somewhere. It would also help to shrink the image down to make more room.

A tip for choosing your break points is by adding no break spaces (`&nbsp;`)to your signature and letting it overflow in more appropriate places.

Example:

```
<!-- This will look the same, but break where the spaces are, not where the &nbsp are -->
Your&nbsp;Name | Your&nbsp;Title
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent iOS from enlarging your smaller-sized text, use this bit of code in the body (to stop it completely) or just in the element you specifically do not want text to be resized.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none
```

Depending on the length of your text, that may not be the only thing you'll need to fix it. You need to use media queries to shrink the text on narrower screens.

Answer (score 0):

just use `min-width: 500px` in `<table>`.

and in all cases avoid using `%` in width, use `px` or `pt`

Answer (score -1):

For your font size try switching from points (pt) to em or px.

```
<span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; color: #D0913D; font-size: 0.7em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;">
<a href="http://website.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">website</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://linkd.in/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">LinkedIn</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="mailto:none@me.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #b6a15e;">email</a>
</span>
```

You should only really be using pt for print. [Here's a helpful chart](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html). Switching may not completely fix your problem, but your text will be a bit more responsive if you use ems.

Comment: Text in emails are best done in ```pt``` or ```px``` for better compatibility with a wider range of devices and email clients.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Points differ wildly between devices and screens. Also it's not like you can't use an em. em is compatible with any device or client that supports CSS 1 +, circa 1996. http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-CSS1-19990111 ....
    
Basically if the client supports HTML it'll support CSS. Furthermore most clients have optimized baselines for an em. (Outlook - 1em/16px /   Apple Mail - 1em/12px / iOS - 13px).

Comment: Out of the 3 choices, I'd definitely take ```px```. Both ```pt``` and ```em``` are inconsistent in email. Poorly optimized "pixel-perfect" layouts will break in clients that render text larger than what you're expecting. With ```px```, it'll always be the same no matter what or where you're viewing it -- as long as you've prevented auto-enlarging of your smaller text. 

[Campaign Monitor on this topic](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3447/should-i-use-em-or-px-when-coding-for-html-email/)